# FirebaseRecylerAdapter gives me an error after adding database reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

This line of codes gives me red lines of error. i dont know what i did wrong. one thing i nottice when i type in "new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter" it gives me override methods of 2 insteads of 1 which is onPopulateViewHolder is missing from what ive seen in a video tutorial of TVAC on Youtube.

here is the code:

```
public class ViewListTutor extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mListTutor;
private DatabaseReference mlistDatabase;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_list_tutor);
    mlistDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Tutors");
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    mListTutor = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.tutor_list);
    mListTutor.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mListTutor.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ListTutorItem, TutorViewHolder> FirebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ListTutorItem, TutorViewHolder>(

            ListTutorItem.class,
            R.layout.tutor_row,
            TutorViewHolder.class,
            mlistDatabase
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(TutorViewHolder holder, int position, ListTutorItem model) {

        }

        @Override
        public TutorViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return null;
        }
    };

}
```

image:

[image: example]

my dependency for UI Firebase Database:

```
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
```

Comment: The `onBindViewHolder` method was introduces in FirebaseUI 3.0. So you'll need to upgrade your dependency to at least that version.